# Fourier transform of imaginary exponential with absolute value argument

Tags: fourier-analysis

When asked to compute

```
FourierTransform[Exp[(-I*Abs[x])], x, k, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
```

Mathematica returns

```
(2 I)/(-1 + k^2)
```

My question is: how much "legitimate" is such Fourier transform? I can't fint it on any book of tables; furthermore when asked to compute

```
InverseFourierTransform[(2 I)/(-1 + k^2), k, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
```

Mathematica gives

```
-(1/2) E^(-I x) (-1 + E^(2 I x)) Sign[x]
```

which does not seem the same as the original.

Comment: How interesting: `FourierTransform[-I Sign[x] Sin[x], x, k, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}] == FourierTransform[Exp[-I Abs[x]], x, k, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]`

Comment: Are you teasing me? If so please be more explicit...